# PHP - Not echoing data from a MySQL database, but no errors?

Tags: php, sql, smf

So I have this PHP code:

- Note: I do use mysqli_connect() further up.

  ```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `smf_messages` WHERE `id_board` = 18");
  if(!$result) {
      echo "<center><p>Couldn't fetch news posts. Error code 2.</p></center>";
      mysqli_close($con);
  } else {
      $posts = array();
      $topicbdy = array();
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
          $posts[$row['id_topic']] = $row['id_topic'];
          $topicbdy[$row['id_msg']] = $row['id_msg'];
      }
      $display = max($posts);
      $display2 = min($topicbdy);
      $qry = "SELECT * FROM `smf_messages` WHERE `id_board` = 18 AND `id_topic` = " . $display . " AND `id_msg` = " . $display2;
      $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
      //echo $qry;
      if(!$result2) {
          echo "<center><p>Couldn't fetch news posts. Error code 3.</p></center>";
      } else {
          while($show = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
              echo "<center><h1>" . $show['subject'] . "</h1></center><br /><br />";
              echo "<center>" . $show['body'] . "</center><br />";
          }
      }
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      mysqli_free_result($result2);
      mysqli_close($con);
  ```

It's supposed to get the latest topic out of the database for my SMF-based forum from the news board, by getting the highest topic id, but the lowest post id. It seems to be doing the query just fine, as I don't get any errors, but it doesn't show the subject or body. What should I do?

Comment: Does the query show as expected when you echo it? Did you check row counts for that data? Also do `$display` and `$display2` hold value?

Comment: in line 4 you close the connection, and call it again in $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$qry);

Comment: @kraysak nope that only happens if first query fails

Comment: In line 4, I check if the first query failed, and if it did, I lcose the connection.

Comment: And yes, I echoed the query and it showed as expected. I even put it into PMA and it selected the proper post.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$result` variable is wrong for second query fetch. For your second query

```
 while($show = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Should be

```
 while($show = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                                         ^
```